# How to convert IList<T?> to IList<T> in C# 8 nullable reference type

Tags: c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

**Description of the problem**

I'm working with C# 8 and Nullable reference types.

I get a warnings with a method like this:

```
private IList<Person?> persons;

// some initialisations here....

IList<Person> GetPersons()
{
   return someList.Where(t => t != null).ToList();
}
```

Warning:

```
[CS8619] Nullability of reference types in value of type 
'IList<Person?>' doesn't match target type 'IList<Person>'.
```

I also tried the following:

```
return someList.Where(t => t != null).Select(t => t!).ToList();
```

But I got the same warning!!

**Solution (a not happy one)**

The only work-around I found was this:

```
IList<Person> GetPersons()
{
   return someList.Where(t => t != null).Select(t => Some(t)).ToList();
}

// THIS REMOVES THE WARNING
private Person Some(Person? person) => person!;
```

However, if I want to make it generic, it does not work....I get the warning again and this method returns a `Person?`

```
private T Some<T>(T? t) where T: class => t!;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the null-forgiving operator on the expression, it applies to the entire expression and any of the nested types (i.e., the generic parameter of the list). Or just cast to the non-nullable version.

```
IList<Person> GetPersons() => someList.Where(t => t != null).ToList()!;

// or

IList<Person> GetPersons() => (IList<Person>)someList.Where(t => t != null).ToList();
```

Check the proposal docs:

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types.md#checking-of-nullable-references

Basically the conversion from `IList<Person?>` to `IList<Person>` would be treated as having a null reference and would generate warnings. But using the null-forgiving operator, it is treated as having a non-null reference (negating the warning).

Answer (score 1):

```
enumerable.Where(t=> t!=null).Cast<Person>();
```

What we wan/need is a Null checking linq predicate/function which will take object? and yeild out object

```
   public static class NullableExtension {

        public static IEnumerable<TValue> WhereNotNull<TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue?> list)
        {
            return list.Where(x => x != null).Cast<TValue>();
        } 
    }
```

allow you to write

```
IList<Person> GetPersons()
{
   return someList.WhereNotNull();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a mismatch in your method declaration.

Try changing this:

```
IList<Person> GetPersons()
```

to this:

```
IList<Person?> GetPerson
```

Comment: The question asks how to *not* do that, since the method already ensures the results aren't null